# How to rotate a function and get coordinates in python?

Tags: python, graph, coordinates

https://postimg.org/image/uzdalt4s1/

The script below will give coordinates of a point going through a sine function (figure A in URL image)

Similar to figure A, how do I get coordinates of a rotated function? (figure B)

```
from time import sleep
import math

x = 100
y = 500
f = 0

while 1:
    print('X: '+str(x))
    print('Y: '+str(math.sin(f)*100+y))
    f += math.pi/50
    x += 1
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: You can multiply by a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
from time import sleep
import math

def get_rotated_coordinates(x, y, fi, angle = 'deg'):
    ''' function rotates coordinates x and y for angle fi, variable
    angle tells if angle fi is in degrees or radians, default value
    is 'deg' for degrees, but you can also use 'rad' for radians'''

    if angle == 'deg':
        fi = math.radians(fi)
    elif angle != 'rad':
        raise ValueError('{} is unsuported type for angle.\nYou can use "deg" for degrees and "rad" for radians.'.format(angle))

    k = math.tan(fi)
    denominator = math.sqrt(k**2 + 1)
    x1 = x / denominator
    y1 = k * x1
    x2 = -(y * k / denominator) + x1
    y2 = (x1 - x2) / k + y1

    return x2, y2

x = 100
y = 500
f = 0
while 1:
    y = math.sin(f)*100+y
    x2, y2 = get_rotated_coordinates(x, y, 30)
    print('X: '+str(x2))
    print('Y: '+str(y2))
    f += math.pi/50
    x += 1
    sleep(0.01)
```